# Connecting client side socket to server socket that written in C++

Tags: javascript, sockets, cordova, client-side

I have to establish socket between c++ server side and client that should be written in javascript, my client side is a Cordova Mobile Application.

My server side is closed to me and I can't change it.

My question is: can I use web socket api of HTML5? means,  my server works with "http" protocol, so can I connect to him with web socket?(my URL to connect is `http://MY_IP`) and if not, how can I connect to this server?